# Visual studio c++ concurrency programming

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a problem with concurrency programming in visual studio c++. The threads in the code below execute one after antoher and not all at the same time.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void f(){cout << "Hello ";}

struct F {
    void operator()(){ cout << "Parallel Word!\n"; }
};

void make_thread(){
    thread t1 {f};
    thread t2 {F()};

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    make_thread();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you tell?

Comment: Make the threads do something that takes longer. Maybe put them to sleep a few times.

Comment: the output is "Hello Parallel Word!"

Comment: @zomnombom Add `Sleep(1000)` to `f` before the output.

Comment: you were expecting "HPealrlaoel World!?"

Comment: Your threads are hardly doing anything that can be performed in parallel.

Comment: You where right. if i put thread1 for sleep, it executes just after thread2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threads are so trivial that, chances are, by the time you start the second one, first one is well underway or has already finished.

Also, if the `cout` output from different threads doesn't clash with each other, it doesn't mean that your threads are not running at the same time, just that it might be protected by some (implementation defined) synchronization mechanism.

If you make them take longer you can see they are running in parallel:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void f() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
        cout << "Hello ";
    }
}

struct F {
    void operator()() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
            cout << "Parallel Word!\n";
        }
    }
};

void make_thread(){
    thread t1 {f};
    thread t2 {F()};

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    make_thread();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Or put a breakpoint somewhere after thread creation and look at *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Parallel Stacks* / *Threads*.